B2B - SFRA - stop AJAX controller action
I want to intercept the Cart-UpdateQuantity route so that, according to some logic, the action is blocked.
I'm using this approach
'use strict';

var account = module.superModule;
var server = require('server');
server.extend(account);
server.prepend('UpdateQuantity', function (req, res, next) {

   ...

   if ( mylogicistrue ) {
      
            res.setStatusCode(500);
            res.json({
              errorMessage: 'my custom message'
            });
            next(new Error('Something went wrong'));
   }

   next();

});

now... it works, but the next(new Error) blocks the normal flow and I get a simple "Unknown" error in the modal.
if I leave the "next" in place, the normal flow is executed, I get my message but the quantity is updated
if I do not end with "next" or I simply "return" I get a blank response
how am I supposed to solve this?
thanks
